# How to remove slope from DEM to better visualise topographic features of vriver systems in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, slope, bathymetry

I have a DEM of a river channel that i would like to remove the overall slope but retain features such as pools, riffles, bars etc. I have used the River Bathymetry Toolkit (detrending tool https://sites.google.com/a/essa.com/rbt/bankfull-centerline-tools/detrend-tool) in ArcGIS before but would like to know if there is a similar pluggin for QGIS or an alternative method.

I want to be able to show these features relative to their immediate landscape rather than getting lost in the overall slope of the DEM when i add a colour ramp.

In the first image you can see i have added a colour ramp to the DEM however because there is an elevation difference of ~30m top>bottom, topographic features such as pools'riffles are hard to see (second image)

I have looked online but can't find a solution.

[image: DEM overview]
[image: Hard to make out pool with colour scheme]

Comment: Have you looked at this alternative to using flow accumulation? The methodology is clear enough in the documentation that it can easily be recreated in QGIS. https://sites.google.com/a/essa.com/rbt/bankfull-centerline-tools/detrend-interpolation

Comment: 'Flattening' the underlying terrain, Clause 10.3 here might help:

http://www.bajr.org/BAJRGuides/42_QGIS_StarterGuide/42_BAJR_Guide_QGIS.pdf